# Set up Apache2 to server multiple directories on the same domain based on URL path

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, virtualhost

I want to host two different sites on the same IP, same server, and same domain using Apache2 on Ubuntu Linux. Let's say I have the following directories which represent sites that will serve content:

```
/srv/www/blog/          #for the blog
/srv/www/mainsite/      #for the main site
```

I want to set up Apache2 so that the following applies:

1. When a user visits `http://mysite.com/` they are served content from `/srv/www/mainsite/`.
2. When a user visits `http://mysite.com/blog`, they are served content from `/srv/www/blog/`.

I had thought I was going to be setting up multiple virtual hosts, but only seems to apply for distinct domains and/or IPs. What do I need to do in my apache2 configuration to achieve the above functionality?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Inside your `<VirtualHost>`:

```
DocumentRoot /srv/www/mainsite
<Directory /srv/www/mainsite>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

Alias /blog /srv/www/blog
<Directory /srv/www/blog>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Ignore the directory blocks if you already have one that covers `/srv/www` - I just put them in to make it clear that you'll need Apache's access controls allowing access to both.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! If this works, I'll be quite grateful and will feel a little silly that I didn't figure it out myself :-)

Comment: That worked! Another thing I had to do was delete the extra virtual hosts files that I had created for the same domain. I kept thinking I had a problem in my new virtualhost setup when really I just had too many files.

Comment: note this is available in httpd.conf file